Hong Kong/US dual citizenship entering China by air
I am a dual Hong kong/U.S. citizen. Plan to fly to Shanghai from HK and enter with my Hk passport + home return permit, then fly to US from Shanghai and exit with HK passport. Would Chinese custom check to see if I have a US visa on my HK passport since it's not a visa-free country for HK citizens? I am hoping to not show my US passport in case they give me trouble with the dual citizenship.
I have looked into the 144-hour visa free policy for US citizens but unfortunately my entry (SHA) and departure (PVG) ports are different so wouldn't work.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

As far as I understand it, there is no requirement to use the same airport for the 144-hour transit, they just need to be in the same region. But that only moves the problem one step earlier.

It is very likely that the Chinese immigration would like to see your authorization to enter the US. You'll also need to present it to the airline at check-in.
